# Is there a way to return value from an array if it is between two numbers?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup

Is there a way to fill in column B if the value in column A is between the numbers in column D and E? If the value is 41 then I want to return N/A since 41 is not in the range of numbers. Everything I tried just filled "Grape" since it was the closest and I don't want a long IF statement.

[image: Data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Lookup Value If Number Between Two Numbers

```vb
=LOOKUP(2,1/((A1>=$D$1:$D$5)*(A1<=$E$1:$E$5)),$F$1:$F$5)
```

IF you change your mind and don't wanna show #N/A then you can improve with e.g.

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/((A1>=$D$1:$D$5)*(A1<=$E$1:$E$5)),$F$1:$F$5),"")
```